# C Syntax for Passing Variables as Void* and Then Casting Later?

Tags: c, void, void-pointers

I'm trying to write a generic "Update my struct" using void* pointers for the variables.  Check it out:

```
typedef enum{
        aa, bb
}myEnum;

typedef struct myStruct{
        uint8_t         a;
        uint16_t        b;
}myStr;

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

void updateStr( myStr* thingee, myEnum flag, void* value ){
        switch( flag ){
                case aa:
                        thingee->a = (uint8_t*)value;
                        break;
                case bb:
                        thingee->b = (uint16_t*)value;
                        break;
        }
}

int main(){
        myStr* thingee = (myStr*)malloc( sizeof(myStr) );
        uint8_t  data1 = 123;
        uint16_t data2 = 456;

        updateStr( thingee, aa, data1 );
        updateStr( thingee, bb, data2 );

        free( thingee );
        return 1;
}
```

The compiler ***hates*** this:

```
# gcc -Wall toy.c
toy.c: In function ‘updateStr’:
toy.c:27:15: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    thingee->a = (uint8_t*)value;
               ^
toy.c:30:15: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    thingee->b = (uint16_t*)value;
               ^
toy.c: In function ‘main’:
toy.c:41:26: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘updateStr’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  updateStr( thingee, aa, data1 );
                          ^~~~~
toy.c:24:6: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘uint8_t {aka unsigned char}’
 void updateStr( mystr* thingee, myEnum flag, void* value ){
      ^~~~~~~~~
toy.c:42:26: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘updateStr’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  updateStr( thingee, bb, data2 );
                          ^~~~~
toy.c:24:6: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘uint16_t {aka short unsigned int}’
 void updateStr( myStr* thingee, myEnum flag, void* value ){
      ^~~~~~~~~
#
```

Can what I'm attempting possible?  If so, can anyone help me with the syntax?  I really just need to know how to call my `updateStr()` function...

```
updateStr( thingee, aa, data1 );
```

...and how `updateStr()` should cast the void* back into the data type I want...

```
thingee->a = (uint8_t*)value;
```

Appreciate any help and/or advice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to dereference your pointers.  It should be

```
void updateStr( myStr* thingee, myEnum flag, void* value ){
        switch( flag ){
                case aa:
                        thingee->a = *(uint8_t*)value;
                        break;
                case bb:
                        thingee->b = *(uint16_t*)value;
                        break;
        }
}
```

Also, `updateStr` expects you to pass it a pointer but you're not.  You should call it thus

```
updateStr( thingee, aa, &data1 );
updateStr( thingee, bb, &data2 );
```

Comment: Yes!  I slapped myself on the forehead when I read your response.  Pointers are a slippery concept, and unless you work with them every day, you tend to forget how they work.  Your response was clear and to-the-point, exactly what I needed.  Thank you!